# Error 101 (net::ERR_CONNECTION_RESET): The connection was reset. WampServer

Tags: php, wampserver

This problem is very weird and random.

I am working with a file with 4096 characters and only I got this error with 4096 characters in that file. I can live with this because if I just type a space or change the end-of-line of file all will work fine, but I wanna know why is this happening, why I got this error only with 4096 characters and only in that page?

Changing the MTU don't work for me: http://maxqubit.wordpress.com/2012/07/04/error-101-neterr_connection_reset-the-connection-was-reset/

Extra info:

- Apache/2.2.21 (Win7 64) PHP/5.3.10
- The file is included in another file and that file is included in another and so on.
- There are several includes of scripts(.js).
- The page is like localhost/mypage/some.php?var=hello&varr=wazaaa
- The end-of-file is "Dos/Windows" in ANSI.
- It doesn't work in any explorer.
- It doesn't work in any pc in a network.
- The firewall is disabled.

Sorry dont be more precise with the extra info, I dont know what is the problem xD
and......sorry my english >__<

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sounds like this PHP bug: [60758](https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=60758)

PHP 5.3.11 looks like it contains the fix for this bug.